# html, css with center div problem

Tags: css, html

I would like to create centered html page with three separated columns (with different colors). I can't find solution for my #container1 in css. The red color is spreading from left side(out of the centered page). Here it is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6W4z.jpg
can someone please help me?
thanks

```
   <body>
    <div id="cela">
      <div id="header">
      <p>hlavicka</p>
      </div>
      <div id="container3">
        <div id="container2">
          <div id="container1">
                    <div id="lavy"><p>Etiam ante est</p></div>
        <div id="stredny"><p>Mauris orci erat</p></div>
        <div id="pravy"><p>Quisque tincidunt congue orci, </p></div>
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="footer">
      <p>footer</p>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </body>
```

CSS file

```
#cela {
width: 80%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border: 1px #110000 solid;
}
#header
{
padding:20px;
background:#008000;
}
#footer
{
clear: both;
padding:20px;
background:#008000;
}
#container3 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:green;
}
#container2 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:yellow;
    position:relative;
    right:30%;
}
#container1 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:red;
    position:relative;
    right:40%;
}
#container0 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:white;
    position:relative;
    right:0%;
    }
#lavy
{
    float:left;
    width:30%;
    position:relative;
    left:70%;
}
#stredny
{
    float:left;
    width:40%;
    position:relative;
    left:70%;
}
#pravy
{
    float:left;
    width:30%;
    position:relative;
    left:70%;
}
```

(sorry for bad formatting, i can't figure out why it is so shitty )

Comment: Are your separated columns #container1,2,3 or #lavy #stredny #pravy?

Comment: sorry, i don't understand your question

Comment: You say "page with three separated columns". Are your "separated columns" divs container1, contarainer2 and container3; or your "separated columns" are divs #lavy #stredny #pravy?

Comment: both are doing their part in "separating columns", but columns are lavy, pravy and stredny

Comment: In my opinion I would drop one set of those divs. That is what is causing your problem. Also divs that do the positioning are 100% wide and 30% left. That is also problem.

Comment: I think the OP may be striving for three columns of the same height, like the "holy grail" solution.  Otherwise, ddawber's post is one possible solution, depending on what OP is trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need to reconsider your approach to this problem.

I'd suggest: 3 floated divs wrapped in a container.

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="column1">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div id="column2">Dolor sit amet</div>
  <div id="column3">Mauris orci</div>
</div>
```

And as for your CSS, there are a few significant things you can build on:

```
#container {
  overflow: hidden; //this will clear the floated columns
  width: 960px;
}

#column1 {
  float: left;
  width: 320px;
  background: #f00;
}

#column2 {
  float: left;
  width: 320px;
  background: #0f0;
}  

#column3 {
  float: left;
  width: 320px;
  background: #00f;
}
```

Essentially:

- Wrap the floats and clear them using `overflow: hidden;`
- The total width of the floats is equal to the width of the container

Comment: i fogot to add overflow hidden in one container. Problem solved. thanks