# html, css img to stop shrinking <div> :)

Tags: html, css, image, border

I have one more question(first one is here: [html, css with center div problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291783/html-css-with-center-div-problem))

So, I have three columns on my web page and when I put image in one of the  and I want to shrink window(browser), image is "going" behind the other div. This is pretty ok, but I would like that this div stop shrinking and to weight of the image become weight of the div, or something like that.

Sorry I don't know to explain it in English, so I will try in images :)

maximized:
[image]

at this point, it should stop:
[image]

and not to do this:
[image]

html part

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styl.css">
    <title>Title goes here</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="cela">
      <div id="header">
      <p>hlavicka</p>
      </div>
      <div id="container3">   
        <div id="container2"> 
          <div id="container1"> 
                    <div id="lavy"><p><img src="http://akiscode.com/projects/SOS/chuck_norris_random_fact_generator_6_3957_2224_image_2561.jpg", width="150"/ > Etiam ante est, tempus vitae adipiscing ac, luctus ut massa. Vestibulum malesuada,</p><div class="clear"></div>
</div>
        <div id="stredny"><p>Mauris orci erat, </p></div>
        <div id="pravy"><p></p></div>
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div id="footer">
      <p>footer</p>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

css part

```
img
{
float: right;
margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
border: 1px solid #666;
padding: 2px; 
}
.clear {
clear:both;
width:100%;
} 
#cela {
width: 80%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border: 1px #110000 solid;   
}
#header
{
padding:20px;
background:#008000;
}
#footer
{
clear: both;
padding:20px;
background:#008000;
}
#container3 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:#CCFFCC;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
#container2 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:#66FF66;
    position:relative;
    right:30%;
}
#container1 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:#00FF00;
    position:relative;
    right:40%;
}
#container0 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:white;
    position:relative;
    right:0%;
    }
#lavy
{
    float:left;
    width:28%;
    position:relative;
    left:72%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#stredny
{
    float:left;
    width:38%;
    position:relative;
    left:74%;
}
#pravy
{
    float:left;
    width:28%;
    position:relative;
    left:76%;
}
```

i have tried to use overflow: scroll, but the result is not very aesthetic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [`min-width` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/min-width).

Specifically, try:

```
#cela {
    width: 80%;
    min-width: 800px;
}
```

Tweak `800px` until it's how you want it.

Comment: this is great, and it is perfect with higher number of pixels. I hated it with all the shrinking. thanks

Comment: `960px` is a good number to use if it works for you. This width will fit comfortably on the screen resolution `1024 x 768`, which is the smallest resolution in real common use today.